# inserting text with speech recognition to a textpad

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a program that takes input from the user in the form of voice and converts it into text with the help of speech recognition module which is working fine, but thereafter when I am trying to insert it into the textpad created trough tkinter, the textpad doesnot appear?? Please check and tell me where i am getting it wrong.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()
text=Text(root)

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something:")
    audio = r.listen(source)
try:
    t=r.recognize_google(audio)
    text.insert(INSERT, t)
    text.pack()
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: as a debugging tool, try (a) moving `text.pack()` outside the `try..except` blocks, and (b) changing the `print()` calls in the `except` blocks to `text.insert()` calls.

Comment: in that case the the error messages will be get inserted in the textpad which i dont want

Comment: As I said, this is a debugging tool.  eventually, your error messages should be replaced by actual error handling, or putting the error message into a status window or something - using print() in a GUI app is not a good practice (since most GUI apps don't run with the console window displayed).  But for now, until you have those other error handling methods in place, just put the error message into the textpad just so you know what's going on.